# SQL: Making a conditional WHERE clause?

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to SQL and am struggling to get the syntax/logic correct for what I need.

Right now I have a query ending in a where statement:

```
WHERE business IN ('A','B','C')
AND
CASE
     WHEN queue = 'Q1' THEN (queue = 'Q1' AND queue_type = 'Y')
END
```

Basically I need all the results, except for data points that have queue = 'Q1'. For those instances only, I need the results to filter down to where queue_type ='Y'.

As the code stands right now, I only get results where queue = 'Q1' and queue_type = 'Y'.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `WHERE queue <> 'Q1' OR queue_type = 'Y' `

Comment: Can queue be NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM mtable
WHERE business IN ('A','B','C')
AND (queue = 'Q1' AND queue_type = 'Y') OR (queue != 'Q1')
```